# XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url]. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I encountered this problem, which i could find any answer. I tried to update text by using x-editable by bootstrap jquery. I have attached the picture [error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQTrW.png) and below is my php code

```
case 'update-number':

        if (isset($_POST['pk'])) {

            header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');


            $user_id         = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
            $fed_id          = $_POST['pk'];
            $last_update     = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
            $number = $_POST['value'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM abc WHERE fed_id='$fed_id'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($query);
            $row= $result->num_rows;

                if ($row) {
                    $query = "UPDATE abc SET 
                    number      ='$number',
                    last_update         ='".$last_update."'
                    WHERE fed_id='".$fed_id."'";

                    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                    echo "Updated";
                } else {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO abc (number, fed_id, user_id, last_update)
                              VALUES ('".$number."','".$fed_id."','".$user_id."','".$last_update."')";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                    echo "INSERTED";

                }
        }

        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I was using base url without www `(ex: http://myurl.com)` I changed to `http://www.myurl.com` and deleted the header in the code. See the code below:

```
case 'update-number':

    if (isset($_POST['pk'])) {
        $user_id         = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
        $fed_id          = $_POST['pk'];
        $last_update     = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $number = $_POST['value'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM abc WHERE fed_id='$fed_id'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $row= $result->num_rows;

            if ($row) {
                $query = "UPDATE abc SET 
                number      ='$number',
                last_update         ='".$last_update."'
                WHERE fed_id='".$fed_id."'";

                $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                echo "Updated";
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO abc (number, fed_id, user_id, last_update)
                          VALUES ('".$number."','".$fed_id."','".$user_id."','".$last_update."')";
                $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                echo "INSERTED";

            }
    }

    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may due to invalid protocol**.

Check your URLs, This error is also occur when using http:// instead https://.

I've faced same problem and fixed it with replaced **http** with **https**.